# MySQL installed on debian (raspbian), is running in background, but "mysql: command not found"

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a linux server running at home on a Banana Pi (very similar to a Raspberry Pi) with a few small websites and databases. Specifically;

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian 
...
```

This has been up and running for some time, and includes an Apache installation, as well as PHP and MySQL. All of these things run automatically on boot, and my server has run faultlessly for some time. In fact it has been many months since I've tried to do anything on it other than the use interfaces on the site and file transfers.

Yesterday I tried to log into MySQL on the command line and the following happened;

```
$ mysql -u root
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

This seemed a surprise to me, given that MySQL is running and my website (PHP, which necessarily has to access and modify the MySQL databases) functions fine;

```
$ top
top - 12:54:43 up 36 days, 21:25,  1 user,  load average: 0.01, 0.04, 0.05
Tasks:  92 total,   1 running,  91 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.0 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    894780 total,   870592 used,    24188 free,   131576 buffers
KiB Swap:   102396 total,        0 used,   102396 free,   597328 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10859 luke      20   0  4776 1472 1036 R   1.6  0.2   0:00.17 top
 2654 mysql     20   0  312m  42m 4248 S   0.7  4.9 257:43.25 mysqld
10746 luke      20   0  9400 1480  880 S   0.7  0.2   0:00.09 sshd
...
```

And `mysqldump` also works fine;

```
$ mysqldump -u root -pnotmypassword --all-databases | gzip > /home/luke/test.sql.gz
-- Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly.
$ ls -lh
total 332K
drwxr-xr-x 2 luke luke 4.0K Sep 11  2014 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    5 Sep 11  2014 ext -> /mnt/
-rw-r--r-- 1 luke luke 270K Mar 30 13:01 test.sql.gz
...
```

I wondered if it is just missing from my PATH so had a look in the directories;

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/luke/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

And found that in `/usr/bin` are the following `mysql*` entries

```
$ ls -lh /usr/bin
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysqlshow: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/cpp-4.6: Input/output error
ls: /usr/bin/printafm: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/myisam_ftdump: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysqlanalyze: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysqlbug: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/innotop: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysql: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/ntptrace: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysql_client_test: Input/output error
ls: /usr/bin/mysql_plugin: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow: Input/output error
total 1.1T
...
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 2048 8388608 109K Oct 20 21:34 mysqlaccess
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.0M Oct 21 03:35 mysqladmin
l????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysqlanalyze
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.1M Jul 23  2014 mysqlbinlog
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysqlbug
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root    161P Oct 21 03:35 mysqlcheck
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysql_client_test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4.2K Jul 22  2014 mysql_convert_table_format
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     24K Jul 22  2014 mysqld_multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     25K Jul 22  2014 mysqld_safe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.1M Oct 21 03:35 mysqldump
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysqldumpslow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4.1T Oct 20 21:34 mysql_find_rows
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1.3K Oct 20 21:34 mysql_fix_extensions
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     35K Jul 22  2014 mysqlhotcopy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.0M Oct 21 03:35 mysqlimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     15K Oct 20 21:34 mysql_install_db
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 21 03:35 mysqloptimize -> mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 1048576 2.7M Oct 22 16:00 mysql_plugin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 21 03:35 mysqlrepair -> mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     39K Oct 21 03:34 mysqlreport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    8.1K Jul 22  2014 mysql_secure_installation
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     18K Jul 22  2014 mysql_setpermission
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysqlshow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.0M Oct 21 03:35 mysqlslap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.2M Jul 23  2014 mysqltest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2.7M Jul 23  2014 mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2.7M Oct 21 03:35 mysql_upgrade
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? mysql_waitpid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3.8K Jul 22  2014 mysql_zap
...
```

Basically, there seems to be some real issues with my MySQL installation, and I am officially out of my depth here and can't seem to find a similar problem on this SE site or elsewhere.

All help/input appreciated. Please let me know what more information could be helpful.

Best,
Luke

Comment: Looks similar to this...http://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too

Comment: Hi @dws, thanks for the link. Looking through the answers, my symptoms mostly closely represent those of the answer referring to a corrupt filesystem! I.e. when I use `du -sh /usr/bin` it is reported as being **much** bigger than the sum of the files that I can see in there. In which case this may not be a MySQL problem at all. Is the solution a reinstall? Are there any other possbilities? Thanks

Comment: @Luke, I would agree that this has nothing to do with MySQL and is likely due to corruption.  As mentioned in the other question, first do a backup if you care about your data at all.  If possible, do the backup from another machine (I know on the Raspberry PI all storage is removable, not sure if that's true for the Banana).  If you can afford to reinstall, that's probably the safest way to fix it, otherwise try `fschk`.